# Can an incorporeal character with Ghost Step Tattoo still hit enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, incorporeal

For the [Ghost Step Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ghost-step-tattoo) in Tasha's, I'm not entirely clear on incorporeal. If a character is incorporeal, can their weapon attacks (esp if non magical) still hit enemies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### If it affected your ability to hit enemies it would say so.

Ghost Step Tattoo states:

> For the duration, you gain the following benefits

The item description tells us only what benefits we *gain*, so the only changes the item makes are those benefits listed. It doesn’t say we can’t hit other creatures with our sword, so we are still able to do so.